# Why doesn't JavaScript recognize the Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0 driver?

Tags: javascript, odbc, adodb, ms-jet-ace

The reference machine is a Windows 7 Professional x64 with Office 2013 installed running Internet Explorer 10.  I check the ODBC Data Source and see I have all my ODBC drivers installed like so:

[image: ODBC Data Source Admin]

Then I go to setup my connection string using the UDL setup dialog, and I also see the drivers that I want:

[image]

I proceed to test my connection properties, and get a success:

[image]

However, when I try to run the following snippet of JavaScript in IE10's debugger, it returns `SCRIPT3706: Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed.`

```
<script language='JavaScript' > 
    var strConn = 'Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0;Data Source=userdb.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;'; 
    var sqlMaxId = 'SELECT Max(idnum) AS MaxID FROM users';

    function getMaxId() 
    { 

        var cn = new ActiveXObject('ADODB.Connection'); 
        var rs = new ActiveXObject('ADODB.Recordset');  

        cn.Open(strConn); 
        rs.Open(sqlMaxId, cn); 

        window.alert(rs(0));

        rs.Close(); 
        cn.Close(); 

    } 


 </script>
```

[image]

What am I missing? Is ADODB dead in a 64-bit world? **Is there a suitable replacement?**

Comment: driver is 64bit and ie is also 64bit?

Comment: The version of office is 64-Bit.  IE can be ran either in 32 or 64, but both fail the same way.

Comment: As an added note, connecting to a SQL instance yields not issues.